# Why isn't a ListBuffer with String and Date elements ListBuffer[Any]?

Tags: scala, types, listbuffer

Let's say I've got:

```
var pairOfObjects = ListBuffer("", myDate)
```

Where `myDate` is of type `java.util.Date`, and it's value is `1970-01-01T00:00:00.000-00:00`

Putting that into the Scala REPL tells me:
`pairOfObjects: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Comparable[_ >: java.util.Date with String <: Comparable[_ >: java.util.Date with String <: java.io.Serializable] with java.io.Serializable] with java.io.Serializable] = ListBuffer("", Wed Dec 31 16:00:00 PST 1969)`

I'd expect it to be something like `ListBuffer[Any]`. In fact, when I put in:

`var pairOfObjects = ListBuffer("", 1)`

The Scala REPL *does* give me:

`pairOfObjects: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Any] = ListBuffer("", 1)`

Why does putting in a Date object to the ListBuffer result in such a complicated type?

Comment: You can explicitly define the type like this.
```var pairOfObjects: ListBuffer[Any] = ListBuffer("", myDate)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A List in Scala is covariant.

Example for Int and Double are subtypes of Double, then List[Int] and List[Double] are also subtypes of List[Double].

Here is the definition for `string` in scala from `Predef` object

```
type String = java.lang.String
```

Java `String` class declartion

```
public final class String
extends Object
implements Serializable, Comparable<String>, CharSequence
```

`java.util.date` class declartion

```
public class Date
extends Object
implements Serializable, Cloneable, Comparable<Date>
```

Now after looking into these definitions both `Date` and `String` class in java are inherited classes from `java.io.Serializable` and not from `Any` directly so you don't see `ListBuffer[Any]` when the list elements are `Date` and `String`.

Thereby from these statement

`scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Comparable[_ >: java.util.Date with String <: Comparable[_ >: java.util.Date with String <: java.io.Serializable] with java.io.Serializable] with java.io.Serializable] = ListBuffer("", Wed Dec 31 16:00:00 PST 1969)`

`Any` is lower type bound to `java.util.date` with `String` which are upper bound to `java.io.Serializable`

Comment: Put another way: a ListBuffer's type is determined by the first supertype the elements within it share? https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/variances.html also helped me understand this concept.

I still don't understand why the type has a few nested structures. Both String and Date are Comparable, so I guess it makes sense that the ListBuffer includes that in it's type along with Serializable.